# Is it good to to implement oAuth for SSO?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I would like to create SSO support for my products. I'm planing to make oAuth login, instead of normal login flow. Is it good to implement oAuth for my own server login?

And if it is fine how should I implement oAuth and how o maintain sessions in SSO in different products?

Using Node.js, Express.js.

Answer (score 1):

Actually OAuth2 is about delegated authorization, SSO is about identity, hence you better look at OpenID Connect.

Comment: i'm not using any 3rd party service for login. SO to login into my own server should I use openID or better I maintain sessions for SSO and use normal login flow for authentication and authorizations?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely take a look at the spec if you decide to implement OAuth.

OAuth 2.0 spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

> Is it good to implement oAuth for my own server login?

Are you asking whether you should implement OAuth yourself or go with a service or product?

Disclaimer: I work for Ping Identity

Ping Identity has a free trial you can evaluate if you choose to go that route. there's a lot of security as it's been a protocol that's been continuously improved for the last decade or so.
https://developer.pingidentity.com/en/signup.html

Comment: I want to  create my own oAuth server, and use it for my own product. I mean in product instead of normal login flow I will use Password Grant type for login. Will that be a good approach? Or should I go with normal login flow?

Comment: If you create your own OAuth2 compliant server you have to implement the spec completely!

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr is it good practice to use oAuth to login to my own server? It will be like Gmail is asking `login with google`. So Can I use password grant type to login to my system? or use normal login flow matching user and password in db and authenticate them.

Comment: Login with Google could also mean OIDC, not OAuth2. Again if you want to build a product you need to implement the specs.

Comment: If you are affilited with Ping Identity (as your LinkedIn profile suggests), then please disclose that affiliation in your post.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the reminder. I wasn't trying to be sneaky.